# Why is UTF-8 coded on 2 bytes for a U+1xxxx character?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to figure how C handles character codes in Unicode. I set my locale to LC_ALL "fr_CA.UTF8" then input a char with `wscanf()` (as an array of `wchar_t`...). I then explore each *byte* and I find something strange. I entered a treble key ( "" copied from a web page) that is U+1d11e. This is actually 3 bytes so I expected to have 2 `wchar_t`. I got: 0x1e, 0xd1, 0x00, 0x00, the last two ones being the null ending char. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] )
{  
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "fr_CA.utf8" ); 

    wchar_t input[256];

    wscanf( L"%ls", input);
    wprintf( L"%ls\n", input );

    wprintf( L"Length = %d\n", wcslen( input ) );
    wprintf( L"%d\n", (int)(input[0]&0x00ff) );
    wprintf( L"%d\n", (int)((input[0]&0xff00)>>8) );
    wprintf( L"%d\n", (int)(input[1]&0x00ff) );
    wprintf( L"%d\n", (int)((input[1]&0xff00)>>8) );
    wprintf( L"%d\n", (int)(input[2]&0x00ff) );
    wprintf( L"%d\n", (int)((input[2]&0xff00)>>8) );

    return 0;
}
```

My expectation was to have 0x1e, 0xd1, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00...

But I have 0x1e, 0xd1, 0x00, 0x00...

What mesmerizes me is that the `wprintf( L"%ls\n", input );` actually prints the treble key correctly... So ***what allows to distinguish between characters U+1D11E and U+D11E?***

Also, I'm running my program in *Konsole* in *Kubuntu* 16.04 LTS and I compiled it with *gcc 6.5.0*... if it matters.

Comment: Could it be that there's a third byte you simply didn't print? [This cleaned up program](https://pastebin.com/Rwzn5TmV) outputs ` Length = 1 1D11E` for `printf  | a`

Comment: So the first thing to do is determine what the size of a wchar_t is.

Comment: Uh...  saved to UTF8 in Notepad gives me bytes `F09D849E`. UTF8 is an expanding system, so it has control bits between its data, meaning you can't read that stuff manually [unless you know how](https://ianthehenry.com/2015/1/17/decoding-utf-8/), and it generally ends up longer than the unicode symbol's value. Decoding the above value by converting it to binary and stripping out the control bits gives the following: `11110[000] 10[011101] 10[000100] 10[011110]` => `00001 11010001 00011110` = `1D11E`.

Comment: @ikegami It seems you're right.

Comment: @Nyerguds I know that there are control bits among data bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would see what you expected if you printed the bytes making up the `wchar_t` values correctly, or if you just skipped that and printed their values without trying to break them up into bytes:

```
wprintf(L"%x\n", (int)input[0]);
wprintf(L"%x\n", (int)input[1]);
```

And the output would be:

```
1d11e
0
```

The way you tried to do this suggests that you're under the mistaken impression that `wchar_t` values are 16-bit and that there's such a thing as a "multi-`wchar_t`-character". The C language is very explicit that there's no such thing. Implementations with 16-bit `wchar_t` are *wrong* (or at least can't support Unicode outside the BMP). Of course one rather popular one is badly wrong...

I just noticed you've also mentioned UTF-8 in the title of your question, but the content has nothing to do with UTF-8 representation. `wchar_t` is (normally; not entirely required) a Unicode codepoint number, equivalent to UCS-4 (or UCS-2 on implementations that only support the BMP). While the locale's multibyte encoding almost certainly has to be UTF-8 in order for you to have access to that character (although GB18030 would also work), UTF-8 is not going to appear if you're working with all your streams as wide character streams.

Comment: Re "*can't support Unicode outside the BMP*", Unless they use surrogates. This is how JavaScript does it, for example.

Comment: I guess the "one rather badly popular one" is the one from Redmond and this is why I didn't understand. `wchar_t` is 32-bit on Linux and 16-bit on Windows. So, if I understand correctly, it took 2 `wchar_t` to represent the string in Linux and 3 in Windows because the codepoint will expand over 16 bits...? But 64 bits in Linux and 48 bits in Windows...

Comment: @ikegami: That's not possible for C's `wchar_t` and the related interfaces because of how they work. `mbrtowc` has no way to output two `wchar_t` values for a multibyte character (this is fundamental, no-go), and the `isw*` functions have no way to report properties of a "multi-`wchar_t`-character" (this might be an acceptable limitation for some users). So no, it's not solvable by using `wchar_t` as UTF-16 (Windows tries to do that but leaves standard C functions broken and makes you use their own thing); it's really not compatible with the language.